# Kubernetes client cert based authentication results in request using system:anonymous user

Tags: kubernetes, client-certificates

I have followed these instructions to create normal user in Kubernetes and generated client certificate https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#normal-user

When I try to send a request to the API server using curl by providing the certificate and key, response comes back as `"message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/apis\"`

```
curl -k -v -L --cert ./userone.crt --key ./userone.key -k --request GET https://<host>:443/apis\?timeout\=32s

<Removed some text>

 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: nginx/1.12.2
< Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 21:53:03 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 237
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< 
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/apis\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
```

Also tried impersonating this user where I had elevated access, this new user is able access pods as configured in the clusterrole and rolebinding. This atleast proves that authorization is working.

```
kubectl auth can-i -n xyz get pods --as=userone
yes
```

Issue seems to be that new user doesn't have access to /apis end point on the API server. Tried adding nonResourceURLs as part of the ClusterRole but that didn't help either.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: read-only-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /metrics
  - /api/*
  - /apis/*
  verbs:
  - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-only-binding
  namespace: xyz
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: read-only
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: userone
```

We are using Kubernetes version 1.18.17 and API server is configured with --client-ca-file option as well. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Hi Venu, you could check also `kubectl auth can-i get /apis`

Comment: I got back yes - kubectl auth can-i get /apis --as=userone
yes

Comment: then I would assume, something is wrong with the certs you have created for the userone

Comment: thanks. Let me look into the certs part again.

Comment: sure, no worries.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with kubernetes version 1.18 but it's working with version 1.19

Comment: that's pretty strange, it does not make sense. I am not sure if there is huge difference between these 2 releases